# What does super(s) in Child-class constructor?

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass, superclass, super

I am currently facing an understanding-problem with `super` keyword. I know that `super` is a reference to the next super class of a specific subclass. Anyway I want to show you my problem:

```
public class Father{
    int length; 

    Father(String s){
        length = s.length(); 
    } 
}

public class Sub extends Father {
    char c; 

    Sub(String s) {
        super(s);
        c = s.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

What does the line `super(s)` do in the Sub class? What will happen if I change the Father class from public to abstract?

Answer (score 2):

If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword [*super*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

If we are talking about constructors, then:

- with `super()`, the superclass no-argument constructor is called;
- with `super(param list)`, the superclass constructor with a matching parameter list is called.

In your example `super(s)` in the Sub class constructor will invoke an appropriate constructor from the parent class.

> What will happen if I change the Father class from public to abstract?

Short answer - when a class is declared abstract, it can't be instantiated:

```
Father father = new Father("Name"); // Error => 'Father' is abstract;
Father father = new Sub("Name");    // Works, if non-abstract Sub extends Father
```

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen if i change the Father class from public to abstract?

If u make Father class abstract,then you have the opportunity to **add abstract methods** to it.

Since an abstract class **may or may not have abstract methods**,So in your code making Father class abstract will not give any error.

> What does the line "super(s)" do in the Sub class

It calls the **parametrized constructor** of Father class.Even if you haven't explicitly called the constructor of Father's class, **default constructor** of Father class will be called.

Answer (score 0):

`super` keyword is always used to refer the super class.

`super(s)` means calling super class constructor with matched argument.

So when you call `super(s)` it calls the super constructor

```
Father(String s){
       length = s.length(); 
    }
```

Comment: Hey you, forgot to answer the second part of his question. :-P

Comment: @TilakMaddy And that is why you should only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sub extends Father {
  char c; 
   Sub(String s) {
   super(s);
   c = s.charAt(0);
   System.out.println(c);
   }
}

public class Sub extends Father {
  char c; 
   Sub(String s) {
   super(s);
   c = s.charAt(0);
   System.out.println(c);
   }
}

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub s = new Sub("INDIA");

    }
}
```

O/P: 5  I

if you change father class to Abstract than also will be same 
Explanation:
super(s) is the keyword used to call super class constructor so it just call a Father(super) class with argument constructor 
 if you change your father class as abstract class there functionality will be same as you are not removing your 1 argument constructor so it will same way to call your abstract class constructor